# android mapview

Tags: android

Logcat showing following error

```
03-26 17:41:51.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(479): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-26 17:41:51.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(479): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.sampled/com.sampled.main}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sampled.main in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.sampled-2.apk]
03-26 17:41:51.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(479):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
03-26 17:41:51.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(479):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-26 17:41:51.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(479):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-26 17:41:51.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(479):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-26 17:41:51.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(479):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-26 17:41:51.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(479):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-26 17:41:51.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(479):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-26 17:41:51.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(479):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 17:41:51.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(479):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-26 17:41:51.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(479):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-26 17:41:51.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(479):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-26 17:41:51.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(479):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-26 17:41:51.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(479): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sampled.main in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.sampled-2.apk]
03-26 17:41:51.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(479):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
03-26 17:41:51.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(479):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
03-26 17:41:51.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(479):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
03-26 17:41:51.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(479):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
03-26 17:41:51.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(479):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
03-26 17:41:51.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(479):     ... 11 more
```

My code is as follwing

```
package com.sampled;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class main extends MapActivity {
    private MapView mapView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setClickable(true);
        Drawable marker=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
        marker.setBounds(0, 0, marker.getIntrinsicWidth(),marker.getIntrinsicHeight());
        InterestingLocations funPlaces = new InterestingLocations(marker);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(funPlaces);
        GeoPoint pt = funPlaces.getCenter();  // get the first-ranked point
        mapView.getController().setCenter(pt);
        mapView.getController().setZoom(15);   // cheating. We could iterate
        // and figure out a proper zoom.
    }
    @Override
    protected boolean isLocationDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }
    public void myClickHandler(View target) {
        switch(target.getId()) {
        case R.id.sat:
            mapView.setSatellite(true);
            break;
        case R.id.street:
            mapView.setStreetView(true);
            break;
        case R.id.traffic:
            mapView.setTraffic(true);
            break;
        case R.id.normal:
            mapView.setSatellite(false);
            mapView.setStreetView(false);
            mapView.setTraffic(false);
            break;
        }
    }
    class InterestingLocations extends ItemizedOverlay {
        private List<OverlayItem> locations = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
        private Drawable marker;
        public InterestingLocations(Drawable marker)
        {
            super(marker);
            this.marker=marker;
            //5.34079, 100.28241 is IICP's lat and long
            GeoPoint npark = new GeoPoint((int)(5.34079*1000000),(int)(100.28241*1000000));
            locations.add(new OverlayItem(npark , "IICP", "IICP"));
            populate();
        }
        @Override
        public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
            boundCenterBottom(marker);
        }
        @Override
        protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
            return locations.get(i);
        }
        @Override
        public int size() {
            return locations.size();
        }
    }
}
```

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.sampled"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".main"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
             <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        </activity>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- This file is /res/layout/mapview.xml -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">       
      <Button android:id="@+id/sat" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Satellite"
           android:onClick="myClickHandler" android:padding="8px" />
      <Button android:id="@+id/street" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Street"
           android:onClick="myClickHandler" android:padding="8px" />
      <Button android:id="@+id/traffic" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Traffic"
           android:onClick="myClickHandler" android:padding="8px" />
      <Button android:id="@+id/normal" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Normal"
           android:onClick="myClickHandler" android:padding="8px" />
 </LinearLayout>
 <com.google.android.maps.MapView
      android:id="@+id/mapview" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:clickable="true"
      android:apiKey="0hTcVSW3qp70ciSiaNSqesiGdbjEmewCc4FsHSA" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cleaning the project? Quiet a few times I've resolved a bug like that, by doing that. Not sure why it works.

Looking through your code, nothing jumped out at me, but I might have missed something

Answer (score 0):

You called your class 'main'. Try renaming it something else, like MyTestActivity or something. I'm not sure if 'main' is a reserved keyword, as far as Android is concerned, but it is in Java and is reserved for the method call which is the point of access for a program when it starts.

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned the Project and restarted my eclipse